# cutting mp4 with codec copy results no audio in browser

Tags: firefox, video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I'm editing a video clip with ffmpeg. The original does not play in Firefox browser by itself. It does normally in Chromium. I do something like:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:10 -i INPUT.mp4 -c copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

the resulting clip plays in Firefox but there's no audio. This happens in Firefox (82.0.3), but not in Chromium (86.0.4240.75). In chromium the sound is ok.

If audio is reencoded with

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:10 -i INPUT.mp4 -c:v copy -ab 360kb OUTPUT.mp4
```

resulting clip is playing ok in Firefox.

Could anyone explain what is happening here and is it possible to cut the mp4 without reencoding audio resulting in a clip that plays in Firefox too?

Some data:

`ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2`

ffprobe INPUT.mp4:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'INPUT.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: iso4avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2020-11-13T18:45:37.000000Z
    com.apple.proapps.clipID: INPUT
    com.blackmagic-design.camera.dateRecorded: 2020:11:13
    com.apple.proapps.cameraName: 0
    com.blackmagic-design.camera.uuid: BDB766E79E646CBB82E3EB986EA1EA-0
  Duration: 02:01:38.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6047 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 5909 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-11-13T18:45:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H264/AVC
      timecode        : 19:45:35:04
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-11-13T18:45:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 19:45:35:04
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-11-13T18:45:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 19:45:35:04
```

ffprobe OUTPUT.mp4

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'OUTPUT.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 01:34:48.02, start: -0.016000, bitrate: 6022 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 5889 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 19:45:35:04
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 19:45:35:04
```

ffprobe the OUTPUT.mp4 that has audio re-encoded and works in Firefox:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 01:34:48.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 5889 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 19:45:35:04
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 265 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 19:45:35:04
```

EDIT:

I'm providing links to original files, but a bit of warning, they are 4-5GB big each:

1. [original recording from blackmagic switcher/capture/recorder](https://cb.emanat.si/s/tFgdX5xqkRirNXt) (this does not play in firefox at all, but does in Chromium)
2. [cut version made with `-codec copy`](https://cb.emanat.si/s/rogRatMJHGYy7zq) (plays in firefox but no audio. plays in chromium ok)
3. [cut version with re-encoded audio](https://cb.emanat.si/s/dZoJPa28trk5MLW) (plays ok in both firefox and chromium)

Comment: If you share all the files that are involved in your question - you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann that's quite hard, since they are 5GB in size. will see what i can do.

Comment: I added links. But I also realised the original clip was not playable in firefox.

Comment: Are you trying to play the files locally (just opening a normal file on your computer?), or are you trying to play them from http? The *moov atom* is at the end of your files because you didn't use `-movflags +faststart`, so therefore if playing via progressive download (such as http) then you'll have to wait for the file to completely download before playing. Your files are big so the wait can be long if you have crappy internet speed like me.

Comment: @llogan yes, i'm playing the files locally - drag-drop to the browser. I have noticed the problem when I first uploaded the second file online and played it in the browser via http, so it seems local/http is irrelevant? however the first file throws an error "No video with supported format and MIME type found.". the second plays immediately but has no audio.

Comment: @Luka Your files are too big for me to download, and I couldn't duplicate the issue with a synthetic sample. So I can only guess. First thing is to update your old ffmpeg. Does it work if you use a recent ffmpeg version? ([Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)). Does it work with a short sample file? `ffmpeg -ss 00:05:10 -i INPUT.mp4 -c copy -t 60 OUTPUT.mp4` Does it work if you omit `-ss`?